# Chase the Easter Bunny and collect his eggs

Tags: code-challenge, javascript, ai-player

Chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106513/easter-bunny-challenge

Git repo: https://github.com/AJFaraday/easter_bunny_hunt

The garden is a 2-dimensional grid with 49 rows and 49 columns.

The Easter Bunny™️ is in the center of the garden, minding his own business, holding on to 100 Easter eggs. He'll hop away from where the most people are.

When the Easter Bunny™️ hops, we all know he'll leave behind an Easter egg.

Grab an Easter egg for 1 point.
Grab the Easter Bunny for 10 points.

The game starts with 4 kids, one in each corner of the garden.

The kids can take 1 step each turn, in one of the 4 cardinal directions (North, South, East or West). When they've each taken a step (or decided not to), the bunny will take a move.

The bunny can hop to any position up to 4 spaces away in both the x and y axes. It will decide where it will hop to by the position of the kids.

The bunny can see kids within 5 spaces of it in any direction (I'm using square distances for simplicity).
For each axis, (ignoring the kids in a line with it) it will move away from the most kids it can see. e.g.

- If it can see 1 kid to the right, and none to the left. it will hop 1 step to the west.
- If it can see 3 below, and 1 above, it will hop 2 step north.
- If there are 2 north, 1 south, and 2 west. it will hop directly to a space 1 step south and 2 steps west.

Important quirks:

- The bunny ignores kids on the same row when working out it's north/south hop, and in the same column for it's east/west.
- If it can't see any kids, it will stay still until it can.
- If the left/right and up/down counts are equal, it will reamin rooted to the spot, like a rabbit in the headlights.

The game ends when:

- The Easter Bunny™️ leaves the garden.
- The Easter Bunny™️ drops his last egg.
- The kids catch the bunny.
- The game reaches the configurable turn limit

### Config

You can edit conig.js to change two things about the run:

- `match_limit` will allow you to end the game when you decide (competition will use 1,000 turns)
- `turn_time` (ms) will set the interval when the game is rendering.

### How to hunt the bunny?

Your code will take the form of an array of 4 JS functions, which will each control a kid starting in these positions (in this order):

- North West (0, 0)
- North East (0, 48)
- South East (48, 48)
- South West (48, 0)

The functions should each have this fingerprint:

```
function(api) {
}
```

api is your function's interface to the game (see below).

#### The API

The api object presents these four movement functions:

- `api.north()`
- `api.east()`
- `api.south()`
- `api.west()`

If any of these are called during your function, the kid will take one step in that direction (or the last called of these four directions).
If none of thess are called during your function, the kid will stand still.

It also provides information about the state of the game with these methods:

- `api.my_storage()` - an object you can use to store data and functions for just this kid.
- `api.shared_storage()` - an object you can use to store data and functions for the whole team.
- `api.turn()` - Returns a number of turns taken in this game so far.
- `api.bunny()` - Returns an object of bunny-related info

  {
    x: 24,
    y: 24,
    eggs_left: 100
  }
- `api.kids()` tells you where all the kids are

  [
    {x: 0, y: 0, me: true}.
    ...
  ]
- `api.eggs()` tells you qhere all the eggs are

  [
    {x: 25, y: 25}
  ]

#### Template

Teams.push(
  {
    name: 'template',
    shared_storage: {},
    functions: [
      function(api) {
        // NW kid
      },
      function(api) {
        // NE kid
      },
      function(api) {
        // SE kid
      },
      function(api) {
        // SW kid
      }
    ]
  }
);

- `name` must be a single-word identifier, if you want to run just a single entry.
- `shared_storage` sets the initial state of `api.shared_storage`, it can be used to set data and functions for your team.
- The array `functions` is the behaviour of the 4 kids chasing the bunny.

#### How to participate

Change my_entry to your own team name.

- `git clone https://github.com/AJFaraday/easter_bunny_hunt.git`
- `cd easter_bunny_hunt`
- `npm install -g terser`
- `cp template.js teams/my_entry.js`
- (Write your team code)
- `script/run.sh my_entry` to watch the game
- `script/run.sh` to see all results (if you import more entries)

When you're happy with the result, copy it in to an answer like so:

```
# my_entry - 10 points

Any description you want to add goes here

    Teams.push(
      {
        name: 'template',
        shared_storage: {},
        functions: [
          function(api) {
            // NW kid
          },
          function(api) {
            // NE kid
          },
          function(api) {
            // SE kid
          },
          function(api) {
            // SW kid
          }
        ]
      }
    );
```

#### Competition rules

Official scoreboard will be updated roughly once a day.

This will run until the 19th of April, one week after Easter Sunday (in the traditions which celebrate Easter Sunday on the 12th of April this year).

Comment: Is this intended to be tagged [king-of-the-hill]?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I'd like to tag it king of the hill, but it will be removed if I do. A king of the Hill is only when entries interact with each other. The challenge here is to find a high-scoring path through a task.

Comment: If so, can this be tagged [ai-player]? update: it's not a winning criterion though, merely a tag; should also probably have [code-challenge]

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Thanks, added

Comment: Am I correct that the bunny does not move if it sees one kid above and one kid below, for example?

Comment: @pppery That's correct, if it has balanced numbers, it will stay in place. I've added this to the quirks

Comment: @pppery The github URL was very wrong, thanks for letting me know. Corrected now. (It's also at the top if you want to dig in to the repo)

Comment: @pppery In fact I'd messed the instructions up entirely, could you let me know if you run into more problems?

Comment: Looking at the code, the limit on the bunny's sight appears to not be implemented, and it can see kids anywhere in the garden, even if they are more than 5 squares away.

Comment: @pppery sorry, missed a push, try git pull and try again

Comment: Keep on getting `ReferenceError: Game is not defined` when I try to run it as above.  What am I missing?

Comment: @noodle try ‘npm install -g terser’, sorry

Comment: @Noodle9 sorry, I think it’s terser I missed out.

Comment: Did `npm install -g terser` - no change after that.

Comment: @Noodle9 can we discuss this in the chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106513/easter-bunny-challenge

Comment: Also, what does _"I'm using square distances for simplicity"_ mean? Does it mean the distance from `(0 0)` to `(3, 4)` is 7? (i.e. you used the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)) Is it 5? (i.e. you used regular euclidean distances) Or is it 25? (i.e. you used the square of the regular euclidean distance)

Comment: @RGS it means it looks up to 5 squares away on both axes, describing a square which is visible to the bunny.

Answer (score 5):

## The Run of Doom, score 109

```js
var kid_api = function (api) {
    var bunny = api.bunny();
    var kids = api.kids();
    for (var i = 0;i<kids.length;i++) {
        if(kids[i].me) {
            var me = kids[i];
            if (me.x < 24) {
                return api.east();
            } else if (me.x > 24) {
                return api.west();
            } else {
                var s = api.shared_storage();
                var my_data = s[i];
                if (!my_data) {
                    return;
                }else if (my_data.backaway == bunny.eggs_remaining) {
                    return;
                }else if(bunny.y == me.y + my_data.y && bunny.eggs_remaining != 1) {
                    s[2] = Object.assign({}, s.opposites[my_data.func])
                    s[0] = Object.assign({}, s.opposites[my_data.func])
                    s[2-i].backaway = bunny.eggs_remaining;
                    s[i].backaway = 1;
                    api[s[i].func]();
                } else if (me.y + my_data.y < 0 || me.y + my_data.y > 49) {
                    s[i] = null;
                } else {
                    api[my_data.func]();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Teams.push(
  {
    name: 'the_run_of_doom',
    shared_storage: {
        2: {"func": "north", "y": -1},
        0: null,
        "opposites": {
            "south":{"func": "north", "y":-1},
            "north":{"func":"south", "y":1}
        },
    },
    functions: [
      kid_api,
      function(api) {
        // NE kid
      },
      kid_api,
      function(api) {
        // SW kid
      }
    ]
  }
);
```

Uses only two kids: one that starts on the north side, and one that starts on the south side (this version uses NW and SE, but it could be rewritten to use NE and SW, or NE and SE, or NW and SW fairly easily). With a little more effort, one could do this with any combination of two kids.

A score of 110 isn't possible, since the game always ends immediately after the bunny drops the last egg, so I believe this answer is unbeatable.

Comment: Maybe you should rename it *The Hog of Eggs*! T_T

Comment: No, I think I like "The Run of Doom", given it describes the pattern of the easter bunny; repeatedly bolting from one edge of the garden to the other without actually ever getting away.

Answer (score 2):

## random - 0 to 33 points

Totally random kids!

```
Teams.push(
  {
    name: 'random',
    shared_storage: {
      sequence: 'abcd',
      take_step: function(api) {
        var char = api.shared_storage().sequence[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
        if(char) {
          api[api.my_storage()['key'][char]]();
        }
      }
    },
    functions: [
      function(api) {
        // NW kid
        if(!api.my_storage()['key']) {
          api.my_storage()['key'] = {'a': 'east', 'b': 'south', 'c': 'west', 'd': 'north'}
        }
        api.shared_storage().take_step(api);
      },
      function(api) {
        // NE kid
        if(!api.my_storage()['key']) {
          api.my_storage()['key'] = {'a': 'east', 'b': 'south', 'c': 'west', 'd': 'north'}
        }
        api.shared_storage().take_step(api);
      },
      function(api) {
        // SE kid
        if(!api.my_storage()['key']) {
          api.my_storage()['key'] = {'a': 'east', 'b': 'south', 'c': 'west', 'd': 'north'}
        }
        api.shared_storage().take_step(api);
      },
      function(api) {
        // SW kid
        if(!api.my_storage()['key']) {
          api.my_storage()['key'] = {'a': 'east', 'b': 'south', 'c': 'west', 'd': 'north'}
        }
        api.shared_storage().take_step(api);
      }
    ]
  }
);
```